# Conway's game of life problems

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the code I was given for my assignment.  The task is to find what is wrong with the code.  The code is supposed to implement "Conway's Game of Life" : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life  I can't find where the error is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameOfLife {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int testCase = 1;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Conway's Game of Life");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Cell[][] universe = new Cell[100][100];
        for (int x = 0; x < universe.length-1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < universe[x].length-1; y++) {
                universe[x][y] = new Cell();
            }
        }

        if (testCase == 1) {
            universe[3][2].calculateNext(3);
            universe[3][2].updateCurrent();
            universe[3][3].calculateNext(3);
            universe[3][3].updateCurrent();
            universe[3][4].calculateNext(3);
            universe[3][4].updateCurrent();
        } else if (testCase == 2) {
            universe[49][50].calculateNext(3);
            universe[49][50].updateCurrent();
            universe[49][51].calculateNext(3);
            universe[49][51].updateCurrent();
            universe[50][49].calculateNext(3);
            universe[50][49].updateCurrent();
            universe[50][50].calculateNext(3);
            universe[50][50].updateCurrent();
            universe[51][50].calculateNext(3);
            universe[51][50].updateCurrent();
        } else {
        }

        UniverseComponent component = new UniverseComponent(universe);
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();
        while (input.length() == 0) {
            int neighborCount = 0;
            for (int x=1; x<universe.length-2; x++) {
                for (int y=1; y<universe[x].length-2; y++) {
                    neighborCount = 0;
                    if (universe[x-1][y-1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x-1][y].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x-1][y+1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x][y-1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x][y+1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x+1][y-1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x+1][y].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    if (universe[x+1][y+1].isAlive()) {
                        neighborCount++;
                    }
                    universe[x][y].calculateNext(neighborCount);
                }
            }
            for (int x=1; x<universe.length-2; x++) {
                for (int y=1; y<universe[x].length-2; y++) {
                    universe[x][y].updateCurrent();
                }
            }
            component.repaint();
            input = in.nextLine();
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: swear, seeing third GameOfLife question today.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are lots of people who volunteer their time here to help others learn how to program. To maximize the help you receive, please read our [FAQ] and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). In particular, you should ask a specific question about exactly what you are having difficulties with.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to do your assignment for you (find the error). But here's a strategy:

1. Does the code compile? If not, fix that.
2. Does the program crash when it runs? If so, look at the stack trace for clues. Then use the debugger.
3. If the program runs without crashing but doesn't advance the game properly, try a simple Game of Life configuration for which you can calculate the expected results by hand and look for where the code behaves differently.

For steps 2 and 3, it's important that you master the basics of using a debugger. Good luck.